# FFT Input array number?

Tags: fftw

I want to ask a few questions.

URL of the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SwuRRe-2Jk&lc=UgyiumSTV11t3SQGNU94AaABAg

1.why is the code 
  double  x = new double[] {1, -2, 3, 4 ,5 ,-6 ,7, 8}
  only  inside -2 and -6 to add a minus sign then other numbers don't need

2.I don’t know much about the results in this URL of the video.
  Can  explain it?
  Thank you master

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PHC3.png)

Comment: Could you include the code in your question?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable piece of code and you will get lots of help https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: code  in this URL of the video   In the introduction                                  
code URL:https://github.com/damian-dz/FFTWintro

Answer (score 0):

> 1. why in the code `double x = new double[] {1, -2, 3, 4 ,5 ,-6 ,7, 8}`
>      only -2 and -6 have a minus sign while other numbers don't need

This is only a test vector which would be replaced by whatever signals you want to transform using the FFT. Such signals could all sorts of values, so a test vector that includes somewhat arbitrary positive and negative numbers is reasonable.

> 2. I don’t know much about the results in this URL of the video. Can you explain it?

A full explanation of the theory behind the [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (and the efficient Fast Fourier Transform algorithm to compute it) is beyond the scope of this post. However, from the test performed there are a few things that could and should easily be noticed:

- Computing the inverse transform on the FFT of the input gives you back the original input
- Computing the FFT of a real signal gives you a signal with Hermitian symmetry: first line is purely real, as is line N/2+1 (in this case where N=4, the third line is purely real), and the other lines pair up in complex conjugate symmetry (in this case where N=4, line 2 & 4)
- Computing the FFT of an complex signal does not gives you a signal with Hermitian symmetry